# why php openssl_encrypt returns empty string in wordpress module

Tags: php, wordpress, encryption

I need to encrypt some data in an wordpress data base so i need to create a module to do that. I haven't use encryption so far, so after so research, i came up with this aproach:

```
class ad_enc {
    public $enc_key;
    public function __construct($enc_key){
        $this->enc_key = base64_decode($enc_key); 
    }
    function encrypt($input) {      
        $encryption_key = $this->enc_key;
        // Generate an initialization vector
        $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-256-cbc'));     
        $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($input, 'aes-128-cbc', $encryption_key, 0, $iv);       
        return base64_encode($encrypted . '::' . $iv);
    }

    function decrypt($input) {
        $encryption_key = $this->enc_key;       
        $data = base64_decode($input);
        $data = explode('::', $data);           
        list($encrypted_data, $iv) = $data;
        $decrypted = openssl_decrypt($encrypted_data, 'aes-128-cbc', $encryption_key, 0, $iv);
        return $decrypted;
    }
}
```

The encrypt method works, i can use it and insert it in db. But the decrypt method returns nothing.
At first i was using aes-256-cbc and so i switched to aes-128-cbc. but still no result.
Now, what am i missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: well, that's the thing: if you use-it like this in plain php, it works. but for some reason, in wordpress it dosen't.

Comment: What you're doing here isn't particularly robust. Both the IV and the ciphertext may happen to contain the two bytes `::`, making your output ambiguous (this applies to any separator you come up with). It's more common to prepend the IV to the ciphertext. When decrypting you know that the first N bytes are the IV, so you don't need a separator.

Comment: @Peter, i thought of this. Actually, i was first thinking of using something like ":<>:" . Could this be the problem?

Comment: Using a separator won't make it fail in every case (which is what you seem to observe). The longer the separator the less likely it is to occur by chance, obviously. But there is just no reason to use one because the IV has a known length.

Comment: @Peter, good point. Thanks. But still dosen't solve the problem for now.